# Unable to find metadata db location for Apache Superset in Docker-compose configuration

Tags: database, docker-compose, metadata, apache-superset

I just installed an Apache-Superset platform on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine thanks to docker-compose. the platform works fine, I am able to create new db connections, queries, charts and so on, but I am wondering where are the metadata stored? I read lots of documentation on this subject and all tell that this information is stored in a SQLLite database under ~/.superset folder. I searched the whole superset tree and the same for my home directory without finding any .superset directory, nor superset.db database. I also read that this could be stored in a Postgresql instance, but there is no clue of such a database on my system. My concern is I will not be able to backup this database if I am not able to connect to it. Nor would I be able to migrate the metadata to another DB.

Could anybody help me on this topic?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Have noticed postgres files under below directory in my ubuntu 18.04(Superset 1.2 @docker)

/var/lib/docker/volumes/superset_db_home/_data/